# pygame display resize automatically

Tags: python, pygame

To resize the display, I would write code like this:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

But I don't like the display frame, so I decided to reject it:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500), pygame.NOFRAME, pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

And the problem is start here, I wanna resize the display automatically as pressing a key, or clicking a button inside the pygame window, but I cannot resize my pygame display, automatically.

I did try some code like this(parts of codes):

```
resize_y = 0 # Don't resize when the program start
console = pygame.display.set_mode((370, 500+resize_y), pygame.NOFRAME, pygame.RESIZABLE) # Expands by resize_y

def main():
  main = True

    while main:
      for event in pygame.event.get(): #skip quit code 
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
             resize_y += 100 #Add resize_y

      console.fill((255, 255, 255)) # Fill background with white
      pygame.display.update()


main() # call main
```

There was no Error message, didn't work, and of course I expected extenting display when I press <kbd>D</kbd>.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all flags have to be passed to `set_mode` with the single the `flags` argument. In your code, you pass `RESIZABLE` as the `depth` argument. Use `or` to set multiple flags.

Second, you write:

> To resize the display, I would write code like this: pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)

but you don't actually call `pygame.display.set_mode` after changing `resize_y`.

You're code should look more like this:

```
import pygame

def main():
    resize_y = 0 # Don't resize when the program start
    console = pygame.display.set_mode((370, 500+resize_y), pygame.NOFRAME or pygame.RESIZEABLE) # Expands by resize_y

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #skip quit code 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
                resize_y += 100 #Add resize_y
                console = pygame.display.set_mode((370, 500+resize_y), pygame.NOFRAME or pygame.RESIZEABLE)

        console.fill((255, 255, 255)) # Fill background with white
        pygame.display.update()


main() # call main
```

But note that the `RESIZABLE` flag is basically useless in combination with the `NOFRAME` flag. If you want to change the size of the window within your code, you don't need `RESIZABLE` and can savely remove it. Use it only when *the user* should be able to resize the window.

Comment: The code needs to be `pygame.NOFRAME | pygame.RESIZABLE` not `pygame.NOFRAME or pygame.RESIZEABLE`. Otherwise, pygame only receives the NOFRAME tag